# Add a custom Symfony Notifier channel

Tags: symfony

I want to use my own SMS Channel and use the Symfony Notifier feature.

I have created a new transport module from the example: https://github.com/symfony/twilio-notifier and I want to "call" my module from my project which is a dependency loaded from my personal Github.
I took care to add in notifier.yaml my new transport channel.

I saw that the list of transports is in the table "FACTORY_CLASSES" in `Symfony\Component\Transport` from the `services.yaml`.

How can I add a new channel ?

Comment: Please add some code (services.yaml etc...). You say "impossible for Symfony to understand that there is a new SMS Channel", concretely what is happening ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to add a new channel. You can (and should) use the existing sms channel. But you have to register your transport factory, so that the notifier is able to find it.

To chieve that, add your transport factory to your `services.yaml`:

```yaml
services:
    Acme\Notifier\Transport\YourCustomTransportFactory:
        parent: '@notifier.transport_factory.abstract'
        tags: ['texter.transport_factory']
```

The tag `texter.transport_factory` is responsible to make the texter channel being aware of your transport.

You can find the configuration of Symfony's native transports [here](https://github.com/symfony/framework-bundle/blob/5.x/Resources/config/notifier_transports.php).

Comment: I wrote an article, hope it helps https://link.medium.com/gXhGKEtKrmb